# An exercise of R. Friedman's Algebraic Surfaces and Holomorphic Vector Bundles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, algebraic-curves

This is Exercise I.3 (P.23).

> (X is a complex smooth projective surface.) Let $C$ be a smooth rational curve on $X$. For $n>0$, find $\dim H^0(nC;\mathcal{O}_{nC})$ and $p_a(nC)$ in terms of $C^2$. What can you say if instead $g(C)>0$?

I come up with the following. From the SES (equation (1.10) in the book)
$$0\to \mathcal{O}_C(-(n-1)C)\to\mathcal{O}_{nC}\to\mathcal{O}_{(n-1)C}\to0$$
we have
$$\chi(\mathcal{O}_{nC})-\chi(\mathcal{O}_{(n-1)C})=\chi(\mathcal{O}_C(-(n-1)C)).$$
By Riemann-Roch on $C$
$$\chi(\mathcal{O}_C(-(n-1)C)=-(n-1)\deg(\mathcal{O}_C(C))+1-g(C)=-(n-1)C^2+1.$$
Then inductively we have
$$\chi(\mathcal{O}_{nC})=\chi(\mathcal{O}_C)-\binom{n}{2}C^2+(n-1)=-\binom{n}{2}C^2+n. $$
By $p_a(nC)=1-\chi(\mathcal{O}_{nC})$, we have
$$p_a(nC)=\binom{n}{2}C^2-n+1. $$

However, I cannot get $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{nC})$. For $n=1$, I see $h^1(\mathcal{O}_C)=0$ and then $h^0(\mathcal{O}_C)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_C)$. For $n>1$, I want the vanishing of $h^1(\mathcal{O}_C(-(n-1)C))$, but I can not get it.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_C(-(n-1)C) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-(n-1)C^2)$ and the cohomology of line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$ are well known.